# Django: application skipped in syncdb

Tags: django, django-syncdb, django-settings

I have several applications declared in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.admindocs',
'django.contrib.messages',
'authentication',
'catalogs',
'configurations',
    ...
)
```

When running `syncdb` the `authentication` application is skipped and its tables are not created, but I get no error.

The other applications are ok.

I think that some error prevents the application to be run properly.

Is it right? How can debug it?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I've have it but now it is excluded from INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! There was indeed an error in my code.

Just running `manage.py shell` and asking for `from authentication.models import *` made the error raise.

Comment: it was a circular import: to make it simple, in `authentication/models.py` I imported a class from an application which was listed after 'authentication' in INSTALLED_APPS.